# Html 5 horizontal and vertical align img inside figure

Tags: css, html

Hi can someone help me horizontal and vertical align a img inside a figure

```
 <figure class="frontpagearticlefigure">
    <img class="frontpagearticleimg" src="image.png" alt="image" title="imgtitle" />
</figure>
```

and my css

```
.frontpagearticlefigure
{
    display: block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 250px; 
}
```

Im working with html 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `.frontpagearticlefigure img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }` or use [display: table-cell](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/)